# Store Procedure/Query running slow based on dates in Parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query (that I also made a stored procedure for). In the query, when I use 2017 dates ('2017-09-30' -> '2017-12-31') The query runs fast (1 sec). When I run this as store procedure with date parameters, the query takes forever to run (greater than 5 mins for the same data, partial results).

In addition, when I use 2018 (only) dates, both the query and the store procedure takes even longer to run for less data. I had the store procedure running for 8 mins with no rows loading despite that fact that data exists.

I am not sure what is going on. Below are some times

**Query**

```
Between '20170930' and '20171231' - 1 sec  - 863 rows
Between '20170930' and '20180108' - 0 sec  - 875 rows
Between '20180101' and '20180108' - 4:15 m - 12 rows
```

**Store Procedure**

Nothing really fully loads, *maybe* after 5 - 8 mins I will have partial results

**This is not happening with other store procedures in my database.** When I run the third date sets on the query, my CPU Usage and Memory are normal.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Query:

```
{ Select 
M.AdultQty,
M.ChildQty, 
M.GuestQty, 
U.Usetime, 
cast(U.usetime as date) as Date, 
Right(U.usetime, 7) as 'Time', 
P.Zip as 'Zipcode'
from MUsage M
left join Usage U 
on U.usageid = M.usageid
left join pass P
on M.ScannedID = P.ID
where  p.Level = 24
and cast(U.usetime as date) between '20170930' and '20180108'
and u.code != 12
order by UseTime }
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MEM]
(
@startdate date, 
@enddate date
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

Select 
M.AdultQty,
M.ChildQty, 
M.GuestQty, 
U.Usetime, 
cast(U.usetime as date) as Date, 
Right(U.usetime, 7) as 'Time', 
P.Zip as 'Zipcode'
from MUsage M
left join Usage U 
on U.usageid = M.usageid
left join pass P
on M.ScannedID = P.ID
where  p.level = 24
and cast(U.usetime as date) between @startdate and @enddate
and u.code != 12
order by UseTime

END
```

**Update:**

By adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` the store procedure works for 2017 date ranges but not 2018?

Comment: Google *Parameter sniffing*. Use `OPTION (Recompile)` in `select` and see the magic

Comment: You can clear the plan cache and re-test. --> https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/eight-different-ways-to-clear-the-sql-server-plan-cache/

Comment: Parameter sniffing is the most likely, but this is also a good read on a similar issue - [Benjamin Nevarez - Statistics on Ascending Keys](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2013/02/statistics-on-ascending-keys/)

Comment: As an aside, it is best [to avoid the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Don't be afraid to use whitespace when writing your query. Everything being aligned to the left margin makes your statements very difficult to read.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! Option Recompile worked for 2017 data but the stored procedure is still not running for 2018 dates.

Comment: What indexes (if any) are on the tables being queried?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a query (that I also made a stored procedure for). In the
>   query, when I use 2017 dates ('2017-09-30' -> '2017-12-31') The query
>   runs fast (1 sec). When I run this as store procedure with date
>   parameters, the query takes forever to run (greater than 5 mins for
>   the same data, partial results).

Definitely looks like a case of parameter sniffing. Please try following options.

- Create SQL Server Stored Procedures using the WITH RECOMPILE Option
- Use the SQL Server Hint OPTION (RECOMPILE)
- Use the SQL Server Hint OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR)
- Use Dummy Variables on SQL Server Stored Procedures
- Disable SQL Server Parameter Sniffing at the Instance Level

> By adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) the store procedure works for 2017 date
>   ranges but not 2018?

### Suggestions

- **Avoid using != or <>**

> In almost all cases when we use the != operator (or any other operator
>   in conjunction with the NOT operator, i.e.. NOT IN) index seeks will
>   not be performed and instead a table/index scan is required.
>
> You can try same thing with `>` and `<` operators.

- I recommend putting `NON CLUSTERED INDEX` ON `usetime` column if it
  is not there.
- **Avoid CAST in your WHERE.**

> As a general rule, doing CASTs or CONVERTs on items in your SELECT
>   clause cost almost nothing.  (Note that CASTs or CONVERTs in WHERE or
>   ON clauses can be very expensive since they will keep SQL Server from
>   making effective use of indexes).